# fetching correct row in mysql query using AND OR

Tags: mysql

Need to fetch a specific row from a table but query is returning multiple rows

MYSQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        id, sender_id, msg, name, profilepic, cur_time, cur_date
    FROM `chat`
    WHERE
        (sender_id = '1' AND receiver_id = '3')
        OR
        (sender_id = '3' AND receiver_id = '1')
        AND
        chat.id > '3'
```

Table sample:

```
id | sender_id | receiver_id | msg | name | profilepic
1      1              3        hi    Jay     o.jpg
2      1              3        hey   Jay     o.jpg
3      3              1        hi    Tom     o.jpg
4      1              3        Yes   Jay     o.jpg
```

The row i expect from the query is the 4th with id "4" but the query kept returning several other rows

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: does it help if you add parenthesis around those two OR clauses? `SELECT ... WHERE ((...) OR (...)) AND chat.id > '3';`

Comment: If it's integer why using `'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` has a lower precedence than `AND`, so surround your `OR` expression in parentheses:

```
WHERE (
     (sender_id = '1' AND receiver_id = '3') 
    OR (sender_id = '3' AND receiver_id = '1') 
  )
  and chat.id > '3'
```

---

Consider the original `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    (sender_id = '1' AND receiver_id = '3')
    OR
    (sender_id = '3' AND receiver_id = '1')
    AND
    chat.id > '3'
```

Because `AND` takes precedence over `OR`, it will be interpreted as follows:

```
   (sender_id = '1' AND receiver_id = '3')

   OR

   ((sender_id = '3' and receiver_id = '1') AND chat.id > '3')
```

The parentheses proposed in my answer will force the two `OR` expressions to be evaluated together, like this:

```
  ((sender_id = '1' AND receiver_id = '3') OR (sender_id = '3' and receiver_id = '1'))

  AND

  chat.id > '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, sender_id, msg, name, profilepic, cur_time, cur_date FROM `chat` WHERE ((
sender_id = '1' AND receiver_id = '3') OR (sender_id = '3' AND receiver_id = '1')) and chat.id > '3'
```

Your original query matches rows which have

```
sender_id = '1' AND receiver_id = '3'
```

and rows which have

```
sender_id = '3' AND receiver_id = '1' AND chat.id > '3
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you try to evaluate those two clauses at the same time:

```
(sender_id = '3' AND receiver_id = '1')
AND
chat.id > '3'
```

which will never be true, have in mind that the AND-operator binds stronger than the OR-operator

So just add paranthesis around your two ORs and this should be fine

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add paranthesis the OR condition operands.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb78d/2)